# Populating a Date/Time in Prometheus Alert Manager E-mail

Tags: time, alert, prometheus

So i have an alert rule that gets fired in prometheus when a queue length has been long for a certain period of time.

Through the alert manger, I am able to create and receive e-mails.

My question now is, as part of my e-mail body, I want to have the Date and Time that either the alert manager triggered the e-mail, or of when the alert was fired.

I am unsure how to do this. Whether I can create a label in the alert and populate it somehow with the current date/time, or what? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alerts in the Alertmanager templates have a [`StartsAt`](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/503a6c0569b1225d41347c6ff1570c6b12f93b39/template/template.go#L234) attribute you could use.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks! But currenlty I can't seem to extra the StartsAt attribute. I probably just don't know how to reference the array of alerts properly:   I can get {{ .Alerts | len }} which gives me 1, but if I am unsure how to get to the StartsAt attribute, it is currently telling me "<.Alerts.StartsAt>: can't evaluate field StartsAt in type...."

Comment: Iterate over Alerts, and then get StartsAt from the elements.

Comment: Dear @brian-brazil , how to get current time in alertmanager template? I want to get duration for still firing alerts, but {{ (.EndsAt.Sub .StartsAt).Truncate 1000000000 }} not works, because .EndsAt is null, a get negative result. So I need to replace .EndsAt by current time, I tried time.Now. But, I get error 'function "time" not defined'. Is it possible to get duration in email for firing alerts without modifying every alert rule by adding timestamp to them?

Comment: ```{{ .StartsAt | since }}``` also works for me to get the alert duration.

Comment: @brian-brazil any advice how to import the "StartAt" field as a lable of the alert?

Comment: @A.Villegas I am trying |since filter in alertmanager slack template, but I get error 'function \"since\" not defined'

Answer (score 6):

```
- alert: Alert
  for: 5m
  expr: ...
  annotations:
    timestamp: >
      time: {{ with query "time()" }}{{ . | first | value | humanizeTimestamp }}{{ end }}
```

I still find iterating alerts and getting the value of timeseries or timestamp in alert text as difficult. So I have solved this problem in above way. It works, and I am able to get timestamp / timeseries of alert in email body. Cheers.!

Comment: The description to your code does not provide useful information, could you comment on your code?

Comment: Hi Andronicus,
  I have updated rule file. code in brackets contains query, which prometheus executes, and converts that to human readable format.  1). annotations part should have this code to collect time stamp. 
2). under -alert details in rule.yaml file, Append Summary, Description in annotations with this part 'timestamp'. 
3). annotations part should have this code to collect time stamp. 
4). Restart Prometheus server. Now Alertmanager will have alerts with timestamp details.
My need was to collect it is email. It can be collected in another config, since part of alert annotations.

Comment: @Chintaman any luck to add the create time of the alert in the "annotions" field?